# Javascript find which words in an array are contained in block of text

Tags: javascript

If I have a block of text, how can I find which of an array of words is contained in the text? For example, given the array of words:

```js
const words = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"];
```

and the block of text:

```js
const text = "The grass is green, and the sky is blue";
```

I would like to be able to return the array `["green", "blue"]`.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please user filter of Array

```js
const words = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"];

const text = "The grass is green, and the sky is blue";

const filteredWords = words.filter(item => text.includes(item));

console.log(filteredWords)
```